# Counting the Number of Vectors of the Form $\{-1, 1\}^n$

Tags: combinatorics

Let the $L_{\infty}$-norm of a vector $\textbf{u} = (u_1,\dots,u_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be defined as $\text{max}_{1 \leq i \leq n} |u_i|$. How can we find the total number of ordered triplets $\langle \textbf{u, v, w} \rangle \in ( \, \{-1, 1\}^n ) \, ^ 3$ of $n-$dimensional vectors with the property $L_{\infty} ( \, \textbf{u+v+w} )\, \leq 1$. (Notice that $\langle \textbf{u, v, w} \rangle \in ( \, \{-1, 1\}^n ) \, ^ 3$ means that each of the three vectors is a sequence of $1$'s and $-1$'s.

I came across this problem in my combinatorics textbook, and I have been unable to solve it for a  long time now. I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a fixed $i$ you either have $|u_i+v_i+w_i|=3,1$ the way to have just $1$ is you have to choose two to place a sign and the remaining one has other sign. This can be done in $3\times 2=6$ ways by choosing which of the $3$ has $1$ or $-1.$ So the answer is $$6^n.$$ by the multiplication principle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is choosing two to place a sign done in $3 \times 2$ ways or $\binom{3}{2}$ which is equal to $3$?

Comment: You are welcome. The former, but you have to give them a sign, that can be done in 2 ways.